# What Sony A6000 settings will take a sharp in focus picture of a dog running towards me?

Tags: mirrorless, sony-alpha, action, animals

How can I increase my chances of getting an in focus image of a dog running towards me?

I'm using a Sony A6000 with the 16-50 kit lens.

I've tried with the following settings

- Focal Length: 50mm
- Shutter Speed: 1/500
- Aperture: 5.6
- ISO: Auto
- Focus Type: Continuous Autofocus
- Focus Area: Center
- Drive Mode: Continuous-HI
- File Type: JPEG

Dog: Black Lab

I'm low on the ground, and I'm holding the camera steady. When the dog starts running, I center the camera on the dog and hold down the shutter.

Comment: The A6000 appears to have a function to delay the shutter until your subject smiles - so if you can teach your dog to smile on command, I think you have a solution :)   (unfortunately your camera does not appear to have a trap focus function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is to set manual focus and focus at the desired distance e.g. 5 m.

Set the camera in shutter priority, with a time of at least 1/250 and an ISO that suits.

Your next goal is to catch the dog in focus, but you can help that by shooting burst.